# promise based axios (Tinymce : cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then'))

Tags: reactjs, axios, tinymce, undefined

[image]I am using Tinymce and I'm using axios.post to send the image uploaded to textEditor to my back server RestAPI to save the file and return a json response containing the path of the saved file.
Everything is working fine but an error keeps showing up saying :
cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

It's really annoying because my code is doing what I want it to but that error just seems to keep popping up.

It doesn't occurr any bugs but I can't just click the error popup 'x' everytime it does pop up.
I don't think it's a problem with my code because I'm pretty sure that's the proper way to use axios & then.

I think it's getting stuck on a default tinymce code and not mine..?

PLease help.
I'm new to react and have spent days trying to fix this

This is my image Uploading handler code :

```
 const imageUploadHandler = (blobInfo, success, failure, progress, content) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    console.log("들어옴1");

    // Wait for the file to be loaded
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const binaryString = reader.result;
      const arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(binaryString);
      const file = new File([arrayBuffer], blobInfo.filename(), { type: blobInfo.blob().type });

      console.log("들어옴2");

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);

      axios.post('http://localhost:8001/reviews/imageUpload', formData)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("Image upload successful:", res.data);
          const responseData = res.data;
          const fileName = responseData.imageUrl;
          console.log("file name? : ", fileName);

          // Get the TinyMCE editor iframe
          const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
          const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;

          // Find the defaultImg element in the iframe
          const defaultImg = iframeDoc.querySelector('img[src^="data:"]') || iframeDoc.querySelector('img[src^="blob:"]');

          if (defaultImg) {
            // Change the src attribute
            defaultImg.setAttribute('src', fileName);

            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              // Optionally, set the alt attribute
              defaultImg.setAttribute('alt', `reviewImg[${i}]`);
            }

            // Notify TinyMCE that the upload was successful
            if (success && typeof success === 'function') {
              console.log(res.data);
              success(res.data);
            }
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error during image upload:', error);
          // Notify failure if it's a function
          if (failure && typeof failure === 'function') {
            failure('Image upload failed');
          }
        });
    };

    // Start reading the blob
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blobInfo.blob());
  };
```

this is my setup for tinymce :

```
  return (
    <Editor
      apiKey='iokd75awv5mkifdb3j4qp387rw27smpbjgoawllblis65mrq'
      init={{
        images_upload_handler: imageUploadHandler,
        selector: 'iframe',
        plugins: [
          'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview',
          'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'help', 'wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | ' +
        'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
        'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
        'removeformat | help',
        language: 'ko_KR',
        ai_request: (request, respondWith) => respondWith.string(() => Promise.reject("See docs to implement AI Assistant")),
        setup: function (editor) {
          editor.on('error', function (e) {
            console.error('TinyMCE Error:', e);
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        },
      }}
      initialValue={initialContent}
      onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
    />
  );
}
```